# simplest way to append a pair to a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, append

I would like to append pairs to an array with PHP,
this is what I currently have;

```
pairs[0]['key1'] = 'something1';
pairs[0]['key2'] = 'something2';
pairs[1]['key1'] = 'other1';
pairs[1]['key2'] = 'other2';
pairs[2]['key1'] = 'thing1';
pairs[2]['key2'] = 'thing2';
```

is there a way to not have to specify the index?
ie pseudo code;

```
pairs[] = [key1=something1,key2=something2]
```

Comment: What is your desired out put?

Comment: `$pairs[] = array('key1' => 'something1', 'key2' => 'something2');` or in PHP >= 5.4 `$pairs[] = ['key1' => 'something1', 'key2' => 'something2'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
    $arr[] = array("key"=>$i,"info"=>"something" . $i);
}
print_r($arr);
// output => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => 0 [info] => something0 ) [1] => Array ( [key] => 1 [info] => something1 ) [2] => Array ( [key] => 2 [info] => something2 ) ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_push()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) does just what you want

```
array_push($pairs, array('key1' => 'something1', 'key2' => 'something2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
$pairs[]=array(key1 => "something1", key2 => "something2")
```

or

```
$pairs[]=array_combine(array("key1","key2"),array("something1","something2"));
```

(not tested)